# How to resolve the following error:('Broker is connecting', '127.0.0.1') ('Error in client setup', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

Tags: encryption, openssl, ssl-certificate, mqtt, mosquitto

What's the reason behind the error ('Broker is connecting', '127.0.0.1')
('Error in client setup', error(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
while setting up mqtt connection over encryption using ssl certificates.

I have read it a socket error when client is receiving data from the server but how to resolve this error.And what can be the reasons behind this error.

client.tls_set('/etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt','/etc/mosquitto/certs/client.crt','/etc/mosquitto/certs/client.key')

```
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
```

After adding these files I'm getting the error while setting up the client's connection with the server.

Comment: `Connection reset by peer` means that another side (server) closed the connection. You may need to check the server logs or if you think that the exception is caused by ssl, you may want to enable debugging the ssl/tls messages

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But this I know and i wanted to ask how to deal with it.The few things which were given on internet I have already tried and still not working. Can you suggest some suitable solution to this?

Comment: Is your client running on the same computer as mosquito or a different computer?

Comment: On the same system.